Unable to load a RealityKit .skybox image from Xcode folder reference
I am creating a simple macOS app in SwiftUI to view RealityKit entities with .skybox lighting applied. Specifically, I found this and this, which I used for guidance.
I have created a "Lighting.skybox" folder on my Desktop with one .exr (from AmbientCG) file inside, and added the folder as a reference to the project. The folder icon in Xcode has the arrow to prove this. In Xcode, when I click on the .exr file, it is correctly displayed in the main window.
My problem however is that the app crashes when attempting to load the .exr file, with the error:
    ModelShowcase/ContentView.swift:169: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: RealityKit.EnvironmentResource.(unknown context at $22f3b2788).LoadError.resourceNotFound("Lighting.skybox/DaySkyHDRI026A_4K-HDR")

My function is really simple:
func loadHDRiLighting(for arView: ARView, with filename: String) {
    
    let skyboxResource = try! EnvironmentResource.load(named: "Lighting.skybox/\(filename)")
    
    arView.environment.lighting.resource = skyboxResource
    arView.environment.background = .skybox(skyboxResource)
}

I have tried loading the file with, as above, and without the folder name, but the result is the same.
Any clues what could be the reason?

The first thing that jumps out to me is the extension should be left off. So it should look like this:
let skyboxResource = try! EnvironmentResource.load(named: "Lighting").
You'll also want to check capitalization. As of Xcode 16, if the directory name is Lighting.skybox, use Lighting in the .load(). If the directory name is lighting.skybox, use lighting in the .load().

@StephenEmery I have tried any possible combination. The official docs say that the folder must be referenced, but I have copied the .exr file into the bundle, tried accessing it with, and without the extension, and from inside and without a folder, but the problem remains. I am almost convinced that it may be a bug in Xcode at this point, but I am very open to anyone and their suggestions.

Try this: Build the app on a simulator. After the app is installed, go to /Users/[yourusername]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices and look for the simulator UDID with the most recent Date modified. You should be able to find your ipa file in there. Right click the ipa and choose Show package contents. See if your Lighting.realityenv file is in the there somewhere. If it is, something is wrong with the code. If it's missing, the file is not being put into the bundle correctly. If you have a sample github project, I'm happy to take a look.

I have created a full app with this functionality, here is the link: https://github.com/funbear-dev/USDZThumbnail

Can you make the repo public?

@StephenEmery My bad, repo fixed!

I think I fixed it. The code and project look great! I just moved the .exr file into a folder of the same name with .skybox on the end. I sent you a PR request. Try it out and let me know if it works.

You'll want to put the .exr file in a new folder of the same name with .skybox on the end. Case sensitivity matters in newer versions of Xcode.
So Lighting.exr should live in Lighting.skybox. The skybox folder should be in the top level of the project.
The code should look like this:
func loadHDRiLighting(for arView: ARView, with filename: String) {
    
    let skyboxResource = try! EnvironmentResource.load(named: "Lighting")
    
    arView.environment.lighting.resource = skyboxResource
    arView.environment.background = .skybox(skyboxResource)
}

Note the .load(named: "Lighting") only has the name of the file, no .exr or .skybox extension.

And work it does! Thanks for your contribution. I have merged your PR.
